# Kotlin Return Expression

Tags: android, kotlin

I have google this and searched here but I have hit a wall.

I have a function which is to return an Int. It tells me I need to add another return expression to the overall function but I can't figure out where it needs to go to be done correctly, i have tried a few variations including adding the same return I use within the if statements but before the closing tag which throws up errors within the rest of the code

I call the function like this;

```
var ans = GetQuestion(1)


fun GetQuestion(cat:Int): Int {
val btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
val btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2) as Button
            val btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3) as Button
            val btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4) as Button

            btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            btn4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

            val initialimageview = findViewById(R.id.imageview_Qresponse) as ImageView
            initialimageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_2);

            val viewQ = findViewById(R.id.textview_question) as TextView
            if (cat==1) { // Multiplication
                var a = rand(5,80)
                var b = rand(2,50)
                val ans = a * b
                var opType = " X "
                viewQ.text = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
                val listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans-a,ans-b,ans+a)
                listOfAns.shuffle()
                btn1.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(0))
                btn2.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(1))
                btn3.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(2))
                btn4.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(3))
                return ans
                listOfAns.clear()
            }
            if (cat==2) { // Addition
                var a = rand(5,250)
                var b = rand(2,140)
                val ans = a + b
                var opType = " + "
                viewQ.text = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
                val listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,4),ans+rand(5,10),ans-rand(2,10))
                listOfAns.shuffle()
                btn1.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(0))
                btn2.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(1))
                btn3.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(2))
                btn4.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(3))
                return ans
                listOfAns.clear()
            }
            if (cat==3) { // Subtraction
                var a = rand(80,150)
                var b = rand(2,79)
                var ans = a - b
                var opType = " - "
                viewQ.text = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
                val listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,5),ans+rand(6,10),ans-rand(2,10))
                listOfAns.shuffle()
                btn1.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(0))
                btn2.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(1))
                btn3.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(2))
                btn4.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(3))
                return ans
                listOfAns.clear()
            }
            if (cat==4) { // Division
                var safedivision = rand(3,16)
                var b = rand(2,20)
                var a = b * safedivision
                var ans = a / b
                var opType = " / "
                viewQ.text = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
                val listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,5),ans+rand(6,10),ans-rand(2,10))
                listOfAns.shuffle()
                btn1.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(0))
                btn2.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(1))
                btn3.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(2))
                btn4.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(3))
                return ans
                listOfAns.clear()
            }
  }
```

As a side note I wasn't sure if I have to use var of val when writing var ans = GetQuestion(1) however both methods throw up the same return error so I can amend that later if required

Comment: What if `cat` is neither 1, nor 2, nor 3, nor 4? The function doesn't have anything to return in that case. If you know that this can never happen, you can put an assertion at the end, or throw an exception. Also note that any code in a block after `return` will not run, so `listOfAns.clear()` will never be executed.

Comment: I would suggest using 'when', then you can use: return when() ...

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function body doesn't have `return` keyword, then both sides of if-else must have return in them, for example:

```
fun dummyFunc(Int a):Int{
    if (a > 0){
        return 5
    }else{
        return -5
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need to add another return at the end of your code. But in your code, you don't have else block, so either you will do like the above answer by Priyanka Rajput or you will ad else statement. And after all, your code has reused code in if blocks, you can extract them and add after all the `if`s you have written:

```
fun GetQuestion(cat:Int): Int {
    val btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
    val btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2) as Button
    val btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3) as Button
    val btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4) as Button

    btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    btn4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

    val initialimageview = findViewById(R.id.imageview_Qresponse) as ImageView
    initialimageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_2);

    val viewQ = findViewById(R.id.textview_question) as TextView
    
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
    var ans = 0
    var opType = ""
    var viewQText = ""
    var listOfAns = mutableListOf()

    if (cat==1) { // Multiplication
        var a = rand(5,80)
        var b = rand(2,50)
        val ans = a * b
        var opType = " X "
        viewQText = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
        val listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans-a,ans-b,ans+a)
    }
        if (cat==2) { // Addition
            a = rand(5,250)
            b = rand(2,140)
            ans = a + b
            opType = " + "
            viewQText = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
            listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,4),ans+rand(5,10),ans-rand(2,10))
         }
        if (cat==3) { // Subtraction
            a = rand(80,150)
            b = rand(2,79)
            ans = a - b
            opType = " - "
            viewQText = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
            listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,5),ans+rand(6,10),ans-rand(2,10))
            }
        if (cat==4) { // Division
            safedivision = rand(3,16)
            b = rand(2,20)
            a = b * safedivision
            ans = a / b
            opType = " / "
            viewQText = ("" + a + " " + opType + " " + b + "?");
            listOfAns = mutableListOf(ans,ans+rand(2,5),ans+rand(6,10),ans-rand(2,10))
        }



                viewQ.text = viewQText
                
                listOfAns.shuffle()
                btn1.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(0))
                btn2.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(1))
                btn3.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(2))
                btn4.text=("" + listOfAns.elementAt(3))
                return ans
                listOfAns.clear()
  }
```

While doing this, I have realized that you have a lot of style and coding problems. First, you mustn't call `findViewById` method too much, it's expensive. You must declare your `View`s as global variables and initialize them in your `onCreate` method. Second, you don't use `listOfAns`, maybe you have other plans for it, you will later use, I don't know, but all I know is, your code runs till the line with `return` keyword, which means `listofAns.clear()` will not be executed. And it would be better if you used when instead of if-else

Comment: thank you for this response and for the extra tips. I have globally declared the views and then only initialised upon on create now. I have also restructured the if statements as suggested so that item s that didnt require repeating as written once. As I also activate and deactivate buttons regularly I created a function for that also to minimise code repetition

Answer (score 3):

You can keep variable **ans** at the top of the function as below -

```
 var ans = 0
```

and replace **val ans** from the all if conditions with **ans**. Before the last **}**
add return statement

```
return ans
```

Comment: Thank you, I have maintained var throughout now

Comment: I upped your response as it was indeed helpful but I had to accept the previous response as the accepted answer as ultimately it was the route I took in the end but thank you very much for your help

Comment: No problem, Thank you so much for your kindness.